# Change the grouping level of a newly inserted row (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have 3 levels of groupings in my excel sheet, and I am trying to add a row at the bottom of the sheet. I want the new row to extend the level 2 (and level 1) groupings but not the level 3, but I don't know how to do that. I would really appreciate it if any of you could help me.

Link to image for clarification -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDuNX.jpg 
Note: The new row is added above 16th row.
2nd image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z2Ey.jpg

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us the code.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I didn't even know what to try. That part of the code is simply 'ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert'.

Comment: And what does it mean to extend? Would you like to see "Level 2" in B15 and "Level 1" in A15? Or would you like the row to be second level?

Comment: So, when I add a new row, I want the groups to extend as in the 2nd image (I added it in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Sub:

```
Public Sub InsertRowLevel2()
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel = 3
End Sub
```

It will insert a new row and make it level 2.

However, this is a quite specific feature, working on designing the whole algorithm would be a better idea, e.g. you should not rely on ActiveCell, except if this will be invoked from a command button's event handler (and you check that the ActiveCell is one that you expect to be, not in a different Workbook).

Comment: That solved my issue. Thanks a lot.